# Upload multiple files with PHPMailer safely

Tags: php, file-upload, phpmailer, image-uploading

I'm building a contact form where users will provide some information and maybe upload multiple images.

I'm using code inspired by [PHPMailer example to send multiple attachments](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps)

but unfortunately I see no simple safety checks, (like not trusting MIME, checking max file size, making sure no hidden php script is being injected on my server, etc.)

I have found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004) the "correct"/"best" way to make sure I'm safe.. But in my understanding this is just for one file.

So my question is: How to perform this safety checks for an array of $_Files? allowing for 0 or more images, each not exceeding 5MB and a maximum number of images of let's say 4!

For simplicity assume this is my simple `html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple="multiple">
        <button type="submit"name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

and here is a simple `action.php` file that is inspired by PHPMailer website but without safety checks!

```
<?php
require 'class/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$body = "hey";
  
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->setFrom('mymail@something.com', 'my name');
$mail->addAddress('theirmail@something.com', 'their name');
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) { 
    //Attach multiple files one by one
    for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
        $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
        } else {
            $body .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        }
    }
}
$mail->Body    = $body;
$mail->AltBody = $body;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo ':(!';
    echo 'oops: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo: ':)';
}

?>
```

How to implement the safety checks for the files?

Comment: The PHPMailer example code does not depend on user-provided MIME types; max_file_size is already enforced by PHP itself - but you need to set the value in the form too. if you want to add your own checks and limits, you should add them in the loop in that script, before the call to `addAttachment`. If you want to limit the number of files it will process, check the value of `$ct` and bail if it gets too big. This is all quite simple stuff!

Comment: @Synchro thank you for your attention on this, I tried to follow your suggestions! Would you say this is a safe version for multiple file uploads?

Answer (score 0):

Following @Synchro suggestion here is my tentative solution to integrate multiple file uploads with the safety checks mentioned in the above link

```
<?php
require 'class/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$body = "hey";

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->setFrom('mymail@something.com', 'my name');
$mail->addAddress('theirmail@something.com', 'their name');


try {
    if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
        //Attach multiple files one by one
        for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
            if ($ct == $maximumfiles) {
                throw new RuntimeException('You uploaded too many files.');
            }
            if (!isset($_FILES['userfile']['error'][$ct])) {
                throw new RuntimeException('There is something wrong with one of your files.');
            }
            switch ($_FILES['userfile']['error'][$ct]) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                    break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                    throw new RuntimeException('One of your files appears not to have been sent.');
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                    throw new RuntimeException('One of your files appear to be too big.');
                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors occured.');
            }
            if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$ct] > 10000000) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
            }
            if (false === $ext = array_search(
                $finfo->file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct]),
                array(
                    'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
                    'png' => 'image/png',
                    'gif' => 'image/gif',
                ),
                true
            )) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
            }


            $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
            $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
                $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
            } else {
                $body .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
            }
        }
    }
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = $body;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo ':(!';
        echo 'oops: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo: ':)';
    }
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Those checks look good, but you should do them after calling `move_uploaded_file` and before `addAttachment`, to make sure you really are dealing with uploaded files before you try to validate them. You probably want that check to throw an exception like your others do, so that it's consistent.